# What is the purpose of java packages having unique names?

Tags: java, package

Whenever I am watching a Java tutorial, they always start their package names with com or org, something to do with the domain of the developer. However, I do not get the overall purpose of doing this, because I don't understand how having a unique package name affects anything. Why not just name it whatever and not worry about if someone else has named their package the same as yours? Why does it matter?

Comment: Yes I just figured it out a minute ago but thank you for your response

Comment: great that you understood it your own.

Comment: Take a look at [Central](https://search.maven.org) for an idea of the variety of packages that you might use while creating a Java project.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of java packages having unique names?

The purpose is to avoid *accidental* naming collisions between different codebases, and the problems this causes; see below.

> Why not just name [a package] whatever and not worry about if someone else has named their package the same as yours? Why does it matter?

That's what a lot of people do.  They ignore the issue.

However, suppose you (or someone else) needed to combine two codebases with poorly or unfortunately chosen package names that resulted in a package name collision.

- New classes would appear in packages where they were not anticipated by the original authors.
- New implicit imports would appear, possibly leading to compilation errors or unintended changes in meaning.  (E.g. suppose that one codebase defines its own `Class` class.)
- There could be collisions of fully qualified class names.  In such cases, one class would "hide" the other.
- Code that uses reflection based on package names to find components could break.
- Classloader resource location could break because of unexpected resources appearing or because of hiding.
- At the very least the carefully crafted organization of packages and subpackages would be messed up.  For example, classes would show up in the javadocs in packages that don't make as much sense as they used to.

To deal with this, you / they would have to re-engineer the code to avoid the worst effects of the package name collisions.  Admittedly, a modern IDE's refactoring support could do *most* of the work ... if you do things in the right order.  But not all of it; e.g. reflection, resources and references in javadocs.

And then you have the problem of maintaining a codebase that has diverged radically from the original version of at least one of its components.  Tools like `git` changeset merging *most likely* won't cope anymore  ... assuming that you fixed the problem by changing package names.  You would have to apply any changes from "upstream" by hand, or not track them at all.

To my mind, the last is probably the most troubling consequence of a collision.

---

Since there is an easy way to avoid / minimize the risk ahead of time, it makes sense to do it.

(It is like putting on the seatbelt in a car ...)

Answer (score -1):

Because if they all had the same name there would only be one package, not 'packages'.